# prove that transformation are non linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that the following transformation is not linear
     $T(x_1, x_2, x_3 )=( | x_1 | , x_2-x_3)$

Comment: What properties define a linear transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find two vectors $u,v$ such that $T(u+v)\neq T(u)+T(v)$. For example, try using $(-1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$ since the non-linearity will be dued to the absolute value.
We have $$T((-1,0,0)+(1,0,0))=T(0,0,0)=(0,0)$$ but $T(1,0,0)=(1,0)$ and $T(-1,0,0)=(1,0)$, so that $$T(1,0,0)+T(-1,0,0)=(2,0)\neq (0,0)=T((-1,0,0)+(1,0,0))$$ hence $T$ is non-linear.

Comment: but how can we prove it by taking general values like (a1, a2 ,a3) and (b1, b2, b3)

Comment: Actually, when you want to prove that something is not fitting a property, you only need one counter-example. Here, if you had no idea, you should use general values and then you would see that $x_{2}-x_{3}$ is linear, so that the problem will come from $|x_{1}|$. In which case $|a_{1}+a_{2}|$ is different from $|a_{1}|+|a_{2}|$? Only if $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ are of different signs. So you take such $a_{i}$'s (in my counter-example, I took $-1$ and $1$).